# Почему некорректно работает <table>? (html css)

Tags: html, css, table

Пытаюсь разобраться с . Подскажите почему не отображаются надписи 'привет' и 'пока'?

> Код

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>

    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <style>
      table {
        display: table
      }
      #column1 {
        display: table-column
      }
      #column2 {
        display: table-column
      }
      #row11 {
        display: table-row
      }
      #row12 {
        display : table-row
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <div id='column1'>
       <div id='row11'>
         Привет
       </div>
      </div>

      <div id='column2'>
        <div id='row12'>
          Пока
        </div>
      </div>

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

> По задумке это должно выглядеть так:
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нужны тэги TR (строки) и TD (столбцы) для содержимого таблицы

Comment: А как это реализовать?

Comment: <table><tr><td>1 row 1 column</td><td>1 row 2 column</td></tr><tr><td>2 row 1 column</td><td>2 row 2 column</td></tr></table> упрощенно, почитайте тут например http://htmlbook.ru/html/table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Привет 1</td>
    <td>Пока 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Привет 2</td>
    <td>Пока 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `display: table-column` вообще не в тему.
2. В разметке фигня - внутри `table` должны быть `tr` и `td`, а не `div`ы.